# iOS- BLE <CBCharacteristic: does not specify the "Write Without Response" property - ignoring response-less write

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

When I load any method at that time it shows me this warning where as I am using that characteristic which is retrieving from method

```
var cbChar :  CBCharacteristic
 func bleManagerPeripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic!, error: Error!) {
   cbChar = characteristic
}
```

**I get warning when I try to write following line**

```
[self.cb  writeValue:aData forCharacteristic:cbChar type:1];
```

I am getting following warmning

> [CoreBluetooth] WARNING: Characteristic , notifying = NO> does not specify the "Write Without Response" property - ignoring response-less write

Can any one help me?

Comment: It seems like the characteristic does not support writing. Did you check the `[characteristic properties]` value to check that?

Comment: let me check bro

Answer (score 3):

The characteristic you are writing to does not support write without response, but when you call `writeData` you are passing `1` for the `type` parameter.  1 corresponds to `CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse`.  The warning is telling you that Core Bluetooth can't do what you have asked.

You need to specify `CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse`

```
[self.cb  writeValue:aData forCharacteristic:cbChar type: CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```